# R vector subset syntax?

Tags: r

I am working in R and have found a strange behavior. I can work around it, but it just seems odd, so I was wondering if someone could explain why I get the following output:

```
> xlabs <- 1:367
> i <- c(2:5)
> Date[xlabs == i]
character(0)
Warning message:
In xlabs == i :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> Date[xlabs = i]
[1] "2011-07-19" "2011-07-20" "2011-07-21" "2011-07-22"
```

I don't understand why the logical equals does not apply in this instance, but the simple equals does. I am writing a quick manual for how to do a certain analysis process in R, and I don't want to have to use a "just because" explanation for my readers' sake.

Comment: logical equals applies a vector to a single value rather than a vector to a vector.  You're looking for `%in%`.  `Date[xlabs  %in% i]`

Comment: @Justin: logical equals can apply a vector to a vector, it just does them elementwise

Comment: @DavidRobinson True! Teach me to answer questions quickly

Comment: In other applications, I may wish to select a range in a vector based on a range in a different vector. For example, I could have vectors Value and Time, and I would like to select a range in Values given a known range in time.

Comment: @mnel: Thanks for your good intentions in editing my post, but I copied right out of R and therefore rolled back the revision for clarity. For example, `character(0)` is not a comment but a return from R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator you want is `%in%`:

```
Date[xlabs %in% i]
```

The `=` isn't doing what you think it is. Look at `xlabs` *after* the last line of your example; you are setting `xlabs` to be `i` as if you did `xlabs <- i` as `=` is almost a replacement for `<-`.

The `==` doesn't work because of the way it is doing comparisons. Consider:

```
> 1:10 == 5:7
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
Warning message:
In 1:10 == 5:7 :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

That is doing:

```
> 1 == 5
[1] FALSE
> 2 == 6
[1] FALSE
> 3 == 7
[1] FALSE
> 4 == 5
[1] FALSE
> 5 == 6
[1] FALSE
> 6 == 7
[1] FALSE
> 7 == 5
[1] FALSE
> 8 == 6
[1] FALSE
> 9 == 7
[1] FALSE
> 10 == 5
[1] FALSE
```

R recycles the shorter vector by repeating it to match the length of the longer. As `length(xlabs)` is not an exact multiple of `length(i)` you get the warning, but it is the comparisons themselves that are not selecting anything

```
> 1[FALSE]
numeric(0)
```

hence the empty vector (in your case an empty character vector).

Comment: +1 Or, in this case, just `Date[i]`. `%in%` is good if `xlabs` might not be consecutive integers starting at 1.

Comment: Very good answer, I get what you mean with the comparisons. That's why the `==` works when I do a range that begins with 1. I looked at my xlabs and it is the same as when it started. Here's my code `> i=1:8
> xlabs
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
...
> Date[xlabs = i]
[1] "2011-07-18" "2011-07-19" "2011-07-20" "2011-07-21" "2011-07-22" "2011-07-23"
[7] "2011-07-24" "2011-07-25"
> xlabs
  [1]   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20
 `